# My Samsung Galaxy Nexus won't turn on

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus

My phone is 8 months old, and since I got it, I've had it suddenly die on me twice, but both times it came back to life within 2/3 days. After the second time it happened, I tried to bring it into samsung to get it checked, but they told me because my screen had a crack, they weren't able to honour my warranty anymore. Hence, I'm in this sticky situation where I still have 2 years and 2 months of my contract left before I can even consider getting a new phone.

This time, the phone has been dead for over a week.

I tried these commonly advised tips:

1. removing the battery, leaving it out for periods of 5 mins to even a day or two
2. holding the off button for 30 seconds
3. holding the off + volume (down) button
4. holding the off + volume (up) buttons
5. options 3 and 4 in various successions

And nothing works! Please help! Any suggestions or advice at all would be great!

Comment: Why not going to the vendor and declare it for a warranty repair? Should still be under warranty. Best do that when it just died, so you won't have too much to argue.

Comment: Paid repair should be the choice here.